# undefine attribute of a svg circle with class

Tags: javascript, svg

I really dont know why when I run this code I have this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'cx' of undefined in.
I really would learn how to set attributes on a svg circle with class.

```
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
</svg>
<script>
class Pelota {

    constructor( coorx, coory, radius, colour){
        this.parent = document.getElementById("svg");
        this.circulo =document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
        this.parent.appendChild(this.circulo);
        this.circulo.attribute.cx = coorx; //here's the error
        this.circulo.attribute.cy = coory;
        this.circulo.attribute.r = radius;
        this.circulo.attribute.fill = colour;
        this.avancex = 1;
        this.avancey = 1;
    }
    move() {
        this.circulo.attribute.cx =+ this.avancex;
        this.circulo.attribute.cy =+ this.avancey;
    }
}

var pelotica = new Pelota( 60, 60, 60, "red");
pelotica.move();
</script>
```

Comment: thanks so much , im starting with javascript , sorry for this stupid question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes are set either via the setAttribute method or via the SVG DOM. The SVG DOM does not use an attribute property.

I've shown both methods below the SVG DOM is used in the move function as it's simpler there since the SVG DOM will give you a number rather than a string. I've also corrected the syntax in the move command from =+ to +=

```html
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
</svg>
<script>
class Pelota {

    constructor( coorx, coory, radius, colour){
        this.parent = document.getElementById("svg");
        this.circulo =document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
        this.parent.appendChild(this.circulo);
        this.circulo.setAttribute("cx", coorx); //here's the error
        this.circulo.setAttribute("cy", coory);
        this.circulo.setAttribute("r", radius);
        this.circulo.setAttribute("fill", colour);
        this.avancex = 1;
        this.avancey = 1;
    }
    move() {
        this.circulo.cx.baseVal.value += this.avancex;
        this.circulo.cy.baseVal.value += this.avancey;
    }
}

var pelotica = new Pelota( 60, 60, 60, "red");
pelotica.move();
</script>
```